# jQuery - Apply CSS to div1 if div2 contains a certain word of text?

Tags: jquery

With jQuery how can I apply css to a div, if another div contains a certain word?

So if div1 contains the text 'TriggerWord', I want div 2 to become red. Below is my attempt.
Thanks

```
     $("document").ready(function () {  
       if ($("#div1:contains('TriggerWord')")) {
          $('#div2').css('color','red');
       }
    });
```

Comment: The only thing wrong with your attempt is that you have `document` in quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't quote `document`. Other than that your attempt is correct. The [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector is what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    if ($('#div1:contains("TriggerWord")').length > 0) {
        $('#div2').css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

or with the shorthand form:

```
$(function() {  
    if ($('#div1:contains("TriggerWord")').length > 0) {
        $('#div2').css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3JxE/2/).

Comment: Your code is incorrect. If I change TriggerWord in the html in your jsFiddle then the color red is still applied.

Comment: @jdln, indeed, my `if` condition was wrong. Now it is fixed. The selector returns an array, so in order to test whether there are elements matching this selector I should have tested the length of the returned array. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#div1").html().indexOf('TriggerWord') >= 0) {
        $('#div2').css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex method:

```
$(function() {

    var reg = /Trigger/g;

    if($('#div1').text().match(reg)) {
        $('#div2').css({color: 'red'});
    }

});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/each/NJ966/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    if (/triggerWord/.test($("div1").text()) {
        $("div2").css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```